# How can i get order data using credit memo plugin in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, phtml, plugin, creditmemo

Here I used the credit memo plugin for updating the order data after refund success so how
can I get order data in that function?

etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="add_data_custom"
                type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\CreditmemoAddData"/>
    </type>
```

plugin file

```
public function afterSave(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoRepositoryInterface $subject,
    $result
) {

 //   here I need order is//

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I have updated the answer please try it and update me if it works for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please update your plugin file as below

```
<?php


namespace Tarun\StackOverflow\Model\Plugin;


use Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Class CreditmemoAddData
 * @package Tarun\StackOverflow\Model\Plugin
 */
class CreditmemoAddData
{
    /**
     * @var OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    private OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository;
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private LoggerInterface $_logger;

    /**
     * CreditmemoAddData constructor.
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param CreditmemoRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param $result
     * @param CreditmemoInterface $entity
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterSave(CreditmemoRepositoryInterface $subject, $result, CreditmemoInterface $entity)
    {
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($entity->getOrderId());
        $this->_logger->debug($order->getIncrementId());
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.**